# Session hijack on OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth, omniauth

Im using OmniAuth on Ruby on Rails4.
But some user report, When he use sign in using OmniAuth hee can be other user, like session hijack.

Im not sure my code has some problem...
This code's purpose is that user can login either facebook twitter and email using one account.

- When user does not provide email address, Email is going to be random@example.com
- User can remove social record from registrations_controller
- When they did not register password or email they can't remove social record(because if they can, and they logout they never access an account)

here is my code.

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
<pre>class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def facebook
  if user_signed_in?
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    social = Social.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, provider: "facebook")
    unless social 
      social = Social.new(
        uid:      request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
        username: request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info.name, #facebook username
        provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
        token:    request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token
      )
      begin
        user.socials << social 
      rescue
        flash[:danger] = t("messages.error")
      else
      ensure
        redirect_to user_path
      end
    end 

  else
    social = Social.find_by(:provider => request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider, :uid => request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid)

    if social 
      user = User.find(social.user_id)
      if user
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        flash["facebook"] = true
        sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication 
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else 
      if request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email.present?
        email = request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email
        user = User.find_by_email(request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email)
      else
        email = User.create_unique_email
      end
      unless user
        user = User.create(
          email: email,
          confirmation_token: nil,
          confirmed_at: Time.now 
        )
      end                  
      social = Social.new(
        uid:      request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
        username: request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info.name,
        provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
        token:    request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token          
      )
      user.socials << social
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      flash["facebook"] = true
      sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication 

    end
  end
end

def twitter
  if user_signed_in?

    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    social = Social.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, provider: "twitter")
    unless social
      social = Social.new(
        username: request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.nickname,
        provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
        uid:      request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
        token:    request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
        secret:   request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.secret         
      )
      begin
        user.socials << social 
      rescue
        flash[:danger] = t("messages.error")
      else
      ensure
        redirect_to user_path
      end
    end

  else
    social = Social.find_by(:provider => request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider, :uid => request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid)
    if social 
      user = User.find(social.user_id)
      if user
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
        flash["twitter"] = true
        sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication 
      else
        redirect_to user_path
      end
    else 
      user = User.create(
        email: User.create_unique_email,
        confirmation_token: nil,
        confirmed_at: Time.now 
      )
      social = Social.new(
        username: request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.nickname,
        provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
        uid:      request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
        token:    request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
        secret:   request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.secret          
      )
      user.socials << social
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
      flash["twitter"] = true
      sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication 
    end
  end
end

private
  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
    options  = args.extract_options!
    scope    = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource = args.last || resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource, options)
    redirect_to user_path
  end
```

end

And schema is this

```
    create_table "socials", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "uid",        default: "", null: false
  t.string   "provider",   default: "", null: false
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "token"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "secret"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: ""
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
  def remove_social
begin

  if current_user.email.blank? || current_user.encrypted_password.blank?
    raise t("messages.error") 
  end
  if current_user.unconfirmed_email.present?
    raise t("messages.error")
  end
  if /example.com/ =~ current_user.email
    raise t("messages.error")
  end

  social = Social.where(user_id: current_user.id, provider: params[:social]).first
  if social.destroy
    flash[:success] = t("messages.success")
  else
    raise flash[:danger] = t("messages.error")
  end

rescue => e
  flash[:danger] = e.message
else
  flash[:success] = t("messages.success")
ensure
  redirect_to root_path   
end
```

end

Comment: Can you describe the sequence of events that is producing an incorrect result?

Comment: Here is sequence of events.  
April 16 5:00PM User #156 sign in by email and password.   
April 16 11:00PM User #156 plays website.  
April 17 12:00AM User #55 sign in by OmniAuth then #55 swiched #156.  
April 17 01:00AM User #156 swiched #55, and #156 can edit #55 profile.

Comment: What do you mean with "then #55 swiched #156". Do you mean that user #55 logged in but got the profile of #156? Can you replay these steps on your own? After that, can you strip your code until it still replicates, so it becomes more clear where the issue is?

Comment: Switch I mean is that user id #55 logged in as #156. And #156 logged in as #55. I suspect that one of them logged in as another user by accident (for example #55 logged in as #156). Then edit their profile. Then another one logged in, but profile is other user's profile. So he assumed it's switched. Anyway, obviously one of them logged in as another... I don't know what's happened.